# Reusing Jmeter Random Variable in the same request

Tags: random, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I'm currently using Jmeter 5.1 and "bzm - Random CSV Data Set config" to read random MemberID from a file, And I'm using this variable inside a post, as you can see below.
So, My question is.. Do we have a way to use the same variable and have different MemberID in the same request?

Post Body data

```
[
 {
        "memberExternalId": "${MemberId}",
    }

    {
        "memberExternalId": "${MemberId}",
    } 
 }
]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Random CSV Data Set Config will read the next value **on next iteration** of the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) or [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) or derivative

If you want to read the next line within the bounds of the same request you will have to switch to the [__CSVRead() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead) like:

```
[
 {
        "memberExternalId": "${__CSVRead(test.csv,0)} ${__CSVRead(test.csv,next)}",
    }

    {
        "memberExternalId": "${__CSVRead(test.csv,0)} ${__CSVRead(test.csv,next)}",
    } 
 }
]
```

So if you have a `test.csv` file like:

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
```

In 1st iteration you will send `line1` and `line2`, in 2nd iteration `line3` and `line4`, etc.

Demo:

[image]

More information: [How to Pick Different CSV Files at JMeter Runtime](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-pick-different-csv-files-at-jmeter-runtime)

The file can be "randomized" in advance either by your favourite text/CSV editor or using [JSR232 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) in [setUp Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#setUp_Thread_Group)